# CrawlSpider Rule not working for a link that actually exists in target site

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm stuck trying to find a way to make my spider work. This is the scenario: I'm trying to find all the URLs of a specific domain that are contained in a particular target website. For this, I've defined a couple of rules so I can crawl the site and find out the links of my interest.

The thing is that it doesn't seem to work, even when I know that there are links with the proper format inside the website.

This is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class sp(CrawlSpider):
     name = 'sp'

     start_urls = ['https://nationalpavementexpo.com/show/floor-plan-exhibitor-list/']

     custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 4
     }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True, allow_domains='a2zinc.net'), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True, canonicalize=True, allow_domains = 'nationalpavementexpo.com'))
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.request.url)
        yield {'link':response.request.url}
```

So, in summary, I'm trying to find all the links from 'a2zinc.net' contained inside https://nationalpavementexpo.com/show/floor-plan-exhibitor-list/ and its subsections.

As you guys can see, there are at least 3 occurrences of the desired links inside the target website.

The funny thing is that when I test the spider using another target site (like [this one](https://www.vinexpoamerica.com/exhibitor-list/)) that also contains links of interest, it works as expected and I can't really see the difference.

Also, if I define a Link Extractor instance (as in the snippet below) inside a parsing method, it is also capable of finding the desired links, but I think this won't be the best way of using CrawlSpider + Rules.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    le = LinkExtractor(allow_domains='a2zinc.net')
    links = le.extract_links(response)

    for link in links:
        yield {'link': link.url}
```

any idea what the cause of the problem could be?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. The only issue is that you have set the logging level to `INFO` while the links that are being extracted are returning status code `403` which is only visible at the `DEBUG` level. Comment out your custom settings and you will see that the links are being extracted.

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class sp(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sp'

    start_urls = ['https://nationalpavementexpo.com/show/floor-plan-exhibitor-list/']

    custom_settings = {
    # 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    # 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 4
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains='a2zinc.net'), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True, canonicalize=True, allow_domains = 'nationalpavementexpo.com'))
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.request.url)
        yield {'link':response.request.url}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: scraping output]

Comment: ooh, I see, can't believe it was that. so, allowing default logs and adding HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES  = [403] to the settings did the trick for me. thank you so much!